# Is there a part of a windows file that can't be modified?

Tags: windows, operating-system, filesystems

I'm trying to accomplish something that will let a user download a file from a web application onto their system. The file will contain a unique five digit code. Using this unique five digit code the users can search for a file in their file system.

I'm wondering where is the best place to put this five digit code in a file so that users can easily search for the file. The simplest approach would be to put it in the name of the file, however, users can change the name of the file easily.

I'm looking for a filed where I can put the code so that users won't be able to modify it but will still be able to search for it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you say File.. what kind of file format do you mean. I'm asking because a file is just a pile of bytes and you can append your  5 digit code every where in the file, if it is your own file format. But if you tell us which file format you use, probably there are some fields which can be used to search for it. As example Tiff has many tags. Images have other meta data. etc

Comment: I'm looking at JPEG, and TIFF image. These formats do have metadata fields in which I can add the five digit code. However, I'm not sure whether windows can search through the files specific metadata fields.